# barra de progresso não está atualizando corretamente

Tags: java, javafx

Estou desenvolvendo um sincronizador de dados, onde a cada 5 segundos verifico se existem dados a serem sincronizados. A parte da sincronização com o tempo de checagem a cada 5 segundos já está funcionando. Entretanto, não consegui fazer a barra de progresso acompanhar o progresso da Task, ou seja, ir de 0 à 100 a cada iteração do laço. Segue meu código:

```
 public void timerSincronizacao05Secs() {
    Task sincronizacaoTask05Secs = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            while (isRunning == false) {
                isRunning = true;
                System.out.println("iniciou  em.....: " + new Date());
                fachada.sincronizarProdutos();
                barraProgresso.setProgress(0.50);
                fachada.sincronizarClientes();
                barraProgresso.setProgress(barraProgresso.getProgress() + 0.50);
                System.out.println("terminou em.....: " + new Date());
                isRunning = false;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    lblteste.textProperty().bind(sincronizacaoTask.messageProperty());
    Thread threadSinv05Secs = new Thread(sincronizacaoTask05Secs);
    threadSinv05Secs.setName("Thread sincronização a cada 5 segundos");
    threadSinv05Secs.setDaemon(true);
    threadSinv05Secs.start();
}
```

Sei que não é a melhor forma de fazer mas, se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço desde já!

Comment: Tipo, ao fim do processo ele não zera a barra novamente, tentei tbm colocar  um label pra informar o que ta sendo atualizado mas tbm não funcionou. E tbm não sei se desse jeito que eu fiz é a forma mais indicada a ser feita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você deu um bind na messageProperty na thread sem usar os métodos de atualização que a classe thread oferece: `updateMessage()`, `updateProgress()`, `updateTitle()`, `updateValue()`.

A forma correta de conectar o progresso da Thread ao progresso da barra é dessa forma:

```
ProgressBar progressbar = new ProgressBar(0.0);

// [...] Algum código

Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        // Método isCancelled() retorna true quando task.cancel() é chamado
        while(!isCancelled()){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
                // updateProgress(workdone,totalwork) valor numérico
                // para trabalho já realizado e trabalho total 
                updateProgress(i, 10000000);
            }
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
progressbar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
```

O código nem não era para ter funcionado já que alterações na GUI só podem ser feitas pela FX Thread (Talvez por isso o bug). Seu código poderia ficar assim:

```
updateMessage("iniciou  em.....: " + new Date());
fachada.sincronizarProdutos();
updateProgress(50,100);
fachada.sincronizarClientes();
updateProgress(100,100);
updateMessage("terminou em.....: " + new Date());

// [...] 
lblteste.textProperty().bind(sincronizacaoTask.messageProperty());
progressbar.progressProperty().bind(sincronizacaoTask.progressProperty());
```

Comment: Obrigado @GustavoFragoso, resolvi pegando um pouco da sua lógica. a barra está funcionando perfeitamente. A única coisa que ainda não consegui foi atualizar o label na tela. Ainda estou tentando, quando conseguir eu posto.

Comment: Resolvi, o problema foi que não tinha dado um `new` no label que iria receber a atualização. Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou :)