# Java FX - Problemas com Threads

Tags: thread, javafx

Bom dia,

Gostaria de sancionar uma dúvida que está me perturbando, como faço para editar um Label a partir de uma Thread utilizando um botão?

Sempre que executo o código recebo um erro, mas se eu executo esse mesmo código sem setar a Label ele funciona perfeitamente, gerando um System.out.println("algum texto"); por exemplo.

Gostaria de uma explicação sobre o assunto e uma solução para o mesmo, grato.

Segue minha classe Exemplo:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Ajuda;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author neto_
 */
public class AjudaController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Label label;

    @FXML
    private Button botao;

    @FXML
    void apBotao(ActionEvent event) {
        thread.start();
    }

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do work
            label.setText("text");
        }
    });

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

}
```

Segue o FXML do meu exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Ajuda.AjudaController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="286.0" layoutY="192.0" text="Label" />
      <Button fx:id="botao" layoutX="274.0" layoutY="144.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#apBotao" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Erro que sempre acusa:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
    at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
    at Ajuda.AjudaController$1.run(AjudaController.java:38)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Você mudou pouca coisa em relação ao código anterior, tirando apenas os services. Como eu disse na pergunta anterior alterações na tela só podem ser feitas pela thread principal. Se é só mudar um Label pra que usar Thread?

Comment: Porque o sistema requer mudanças no label, já que vou trabalhar com uma tela de carregamento e alteração de valores após a mesma, se eu não utilizar threads o programa inteiro fica estático durante a operação do método utilizado. @GustavoFragoso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu propósito apenas ficou claro no seu comentário acima. Se você deseja uma tela de carregamento com atualizações existe um jeito fácil de fazer isso:

```
Label label = new Label("Texto inicial");

Service<Void> atualizacao = new Service<Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {

        return new Task<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                updateMessage("Iniciando atualização");
                Thread.sleep(2000); // Suas tarefas demoradas

                updateMessage("Operação 1 concluída");
                Thread.sleep(2000); // Suas tarefas demoradas

                updateMessage("Finalizando");
                return null;
            }

        };
    }
};

label.textProperty().bind(atualizacao.messageProperty());

atualizacao.start();
```

Quando você cria um vínculo entre propriedades no JavaFX elas interagem entre si (Se forem compatíveis). No meu caso eu usei o método updateMessage(), para que a Thread lance mensagens de progresso, e o vinculei à propriedade de texto do label que quero alterar.

O resultado é este:

[image: Thread]

**Mais uma vez cuidado com várias threads atualizando o mesmo nó (o label no caso)**

Para ver o processo usando um indicador de progresso veja esta pergunta: [JavaFX indicador de progresso na construção da interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269742/javafx-indicador-de-progresso-na-constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-interface/272740#272740)

[barra de progresso não está atualizando corretamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232196/barra-de-progresso-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-atualizando-corretamente/232508#232508)

Comment: Muito bem explicado, obrigado. Mas ainda tenho mais uma dúvida, e se eu quiser setar as porcentagens do progressbar através de outra classe por exemplo? É possivel? Utilizando por exemplo um método que receba valores do tipo double.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nas outras perguntas que eu linkei, tem outros métodos que vc pode usar como updateValue(), updateProgress() etc

Comment: Tranquilo, eu descobri como fazer, me ajudou muito, valeu!